# Adafruit with rockpi 4

Tags: python, adafruit

I would need help from colleagues. I have an Adafruit OLED library installed on raspberrypi working perfectly.
I installed it on a rockpi 4, it installs perfectly, but when I run the program, it gives an error as shown below

**error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 7, in
>
> i2c = busio.I2C(7, board.SDA, board.SCL)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/busio.py", line 35, in
> **init**
> self.init(scl, sda, frequency)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/busio.py", line 123, in init
> raise ValueError( ValueError: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(7, <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cdcd0>) Valid I2C ports: ((0,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cdd60>,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cdcd0>), (1,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cdf10>,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cdeb0>), (7,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cde50>,
> <adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.sysfs_pin.Pin object at
> 0x7f851cddc0>))

**Code:**

```
import mraa
import time

import board
import busio

i2c = busio.I2C(7, board.SDA, board.SCL)

import adafruit_ssd1306
oled = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 32, i2c)

# initialise gpio 23
gpio_1 = mraa.Gpio(37)

# initialise gpio 24
gpio_2 = mraa.Gpio(24)

# set gpio 23 to output
gpio_1.dir(mraa.DIR_OUT)

# set gpio 24 to output
gpio_2.dir(mraa.DIR_OUT)

# toggle both gpio's
while True:
    gpio_1.write(1)
    gpio_2.write(0)

    time.sleep(1)

    gpio_1.write(0)
    gpio_2.write(1)

    time.sleep(1)
```

**Installed:**

apt-get install -y rockpi4-dtbo

apt-get install libmraa

apt-get install python3-pip

apt-get install python3-pil

apt-get install python3-numpy

pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-ssd1306

**testing rockpi 4 commands linux**

mraa-i2c detect 0

00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

20: -- -- -- -- ---- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 3c -- -- --

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

found oled display 0x3c

enabled and turned on i2c display on rockpi 4 i2c7

Answer (score 0):

As it's not listed in your installed list, I believe you will need this python library too - it's also required for busio:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka

You should install this library using PyPi, as instructed here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka#installing-from-pypi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).